# How to enable assertions in the Gradle run task

Tags: java, gradle, assert, assertion

By default, Java disables assertions. (The test I'm using here is `assert false;` as the first line in `main()`.)

I'd like to have them enabled while running my program with `gradle run`. What's the trick for doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a specific flag `enableAssertions` that you can set to enable assertions. Such flags are often more readable than working with the jvm args directly. It comes down to personal preferences I think.

Instead of working with `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` you can add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
run {
    enableAssertions = true
}
```

This configures the `run` task to enable assertions.

The `run` task is of type [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html), have a look [at the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) if you are interested in other parameters that you can set (e.g., `workingDir` or `heapMaxSize`).

Comment: Thanks for referring to the documentation where this can be found instead of just letting this be some magic/mystery/secret knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
     enableAssertions = true
}
```